# Create Photoshop blank images with RGB values from Excel

Tags: excel, photoshop, vba

1) I have a list of RGB values in Excel. The values are in the format of xx,xx,xx in one cell.

2) I want to create a blank image with the colour corresponding to each RGB value in the cell and have these saved as different files named accordingly.

3) Can I do this through Photoshop or do I need other software? If yes, how do I do it?

4) I need the final output to be a png or jpg file.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question, and add some further details. Windows/OSX? What does your spreadsheet look like - please show some sample cells. How big is the blank image to be? What type of image is it supposed to be - PNG/JPEG/TIF? You do not need Photoshop necessarily - it depends id you really need a `PSD` file since you could generate `PNG` files and read these perfect;y well into Photoshop. Maybe say why you are taking them into Photoshop anyway - it may be possible to avoid the expense.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you install `ImageMagick` which is free and available for Windows from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

Then, if you have the following values in a cell

```
255,0,255
```

you can use this `ImageMagick` command to make a magenta, PNG file from it which is 200px wide and 100px high

```
convert -size 200x100 xc:"rgb(255,0,255)" image.png
```

[image]

If your cell values are in hex and you want a JPEG rather than a PNG, the command becomes

```
convert -size 200x1000 xc:#ff00ff image.jpg
```

You will need to use Excel's `ShellExecute()` function to execute the `convert` command, there is a nice example [here](http://www.suodenjoki.dk/us/productions/articles/vbashellexecute.htm).

**Notes**

1. If you don't like VBA, you could also export the relevant cells from Excel as a CSV, and then write a little batch file with a `FOR /F` loop, like [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to run through the cells and call ImageMagick's `convert` once for each cell.
2. Microsoft also ships a program called `convert.exe` (that converts FAT filesystems to NTFS), so you need to be careful with your PATH to select the correct `convert`, or rename the Microsoft one to `msconvert.exe` or the ImageMagick one to `imconvert.exe`.